# What Language(s)/technology was used to make the old school search engines like Excite, Altavista, Lycos?

Tags: search-engine

I'm just doing some research into the Language(s) and Technologies used to build the old school search engines like  Excite, Altavista, Lycos and Ask Jeeves?

What i would love to know is the Technology used to create them originally and the databases used?for example the first version of Google.com was built using Java and Python.

Thank you in advance ;-)

Comment: Please stop applying specific language tags to these questions of yours - better still, stop asking them.

Comment: The original Google search engine was written in C/C++, get your facts straight: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html

Comment: BackRub is written in Java and Python and runs on several Sun Ultras and Intel Pentiums running Linux. The primary database is kept on an Sun Ultra II with 28GB of disk. Scott Hassan and Alan Steremberg have provided a great deal of very talented implementation help. Sergey Brin has also been very involved and deserves many thanks. -Larry Page page@cs.stanford.edu
http://web.archive.org/web/19971210065425/backrub.stanford.edu/backrub.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google employees Jeffrey Dean and Sanjay Ghemawat say in their paper "MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters" that Google used ad hoc distribution of the processing of their big input file for the indexing, including 3800 LOC C++ for one (!) phase.

I guess working code was a big mixture of hand refined high level languages and scripts to pass the data around to many machines. No databases until GFS + Bigtable were around.

Answer (score 0):

Perl was the main old skool language.

Are you getting us to do our homework for you?

Comment: But perl may have not used on larger bandwidth sites, where I would have thought C/C++ would have held sway. Of course the computing power / network bandwidth ratio was rather different back then!

Google os a completely different kettle of fish being far more recent in development.